# Nesting queries in MS access using VBA

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have four queries. I want to compact them into one so I can run it recursively in a VBA script (`On Current` event). I don't want to use `OpenQuery` so as to not have pop ups interrupt the workflow. Please advise.

Basically, what I have are two tables `Salary Payslip` and `Salary Deductions.` I'm trying to calculate all the deductions that took place within the last salary cycle (i.e. in the days between the most recent and second most recent salary date). Once that is identified, I want to return the sum of those deductions (so I can put this in a `salary payslip` form programmatically).

I'll post the SQL code for the four queries below:

QUERY 1:

```sql
SELECT [salary payslip].payslipid, [salary payslip].[payslip date], [salary payslip].[employee name]
FROM [salary payslip]
WHERE ((([salary payslip].[payslip date]) In (select top 2 t.[payslip date] from [salary payslip] t where t.[employee name]= [salary payslip].[employee name] order by t.[payslip date] desc)));
```

QUERY 2:

```sql
SELECT First([Show Last Two Payslips].[Payslip date]) AS [end], Last([Show Last Two Payslips].[Payslip date]) AS beginning, [Salary Payslip].[Employee Name]
FROM [Salary Deductions], [Show Last Two Payslips], [Salary Payslip]
GROUP BY [Salary Payslip].[Employee Name];
```

QUERY 3:

```sql
SELECT [Salary Deductions].[Employee Name], [Salary Deductions].[Deduction Amount <USD>], [Salary Deductions].[Deduction Date]
FROM [Set Beginning and End of Deductions], [Salary Deductions]
WHERE ((([Salary Deductions].[Deduction Date])>[Set Beginning and End of Deductions].[beginning] And ([Salary Deductions].[Deduction Date])<=[Set Beginning and End of Deductions].[end]))
GROUP BY [Salary Deductions].[Employee Name], [Salary Deductions].[Deduction Amount <USD>], [Salary Deductions].[Deduction Date];
```

QUERY 4:

```sql
SELECT Sum([Extract Deductions for Salary Cycle].[Deduction Amount <USD>]) AS [SumOfDeduction Amount <USD>], [Extract Deductions for Salary Cycle].[Employee Name]
FROM [Extract Deductions for Salary Cycle]
GROUP BY [Extract Deductions for Salary Cycle].[Employee Name];
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply save all your queries as stored Access queries which tend to be more efficient than VBA string SQL statements and [saved queries](http://allenbrowne.com/QueryPerfIssue.html) are preferred to nested subqueries in MS Access.

Then, use a [**`DLookUp`**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dlookup-function-8896cb03-e31f-45d1-86db-bed10dca5937) expression on last query in the `ControlSource` of the desired form textbox with criteria to match current employee displayed on form.

```vb
=DLookUp("[SumOfDeduction Amount <USD>]", "MyQuery4", "[Employee Name] = '" & Form!MyForm!MyEmployeeNameTextbox & "'")
```

Ideally, you should use Employee ID (not name) in *all* queries for easier matching criteria (i.e., without single quotes):

```vb
=DLookUp("[SumOfDeduction Amount <USD>]", "MyQuery4", "[EmployeeID] = " & Form!MyForm!MyEmployeeIDTextbox)
```

With this approach you would need no VBA code!

Comment: Nested subqueries don't work very well in Access, but if you have a SQL Server backend, you can use a single passthru query (or View) constructed of a series of CTE's (Common Table Expression) and have everything in one place. It would like WITH Query1 AS (SELECT ...), Query 2 AS (SELECT ...), Query3 AS (SELECT..) SELECT ,,,     where each SELECT can refer to the named subqueries.

Comment: @TomRobinson, where are subqueries used here? As mentioned, layered saved queries are preferred over subqueries in MS Access. See Allen Browne's link. And I am well aware of CTEs but OP does not indicate any non-Access backend use.

Comment: OK they aren't actually subqueries, they are expressions. They are an easier-to-read alternative to subqueries. I've used the layered save queries for years, but after converting a large app to SQL Server, I've really appreciated the ability to define a view which replaces nested saved queries with everything spelled out in one place. (It was a comment, not an answer.)