# SQL in MS Access (sum data in a secondary table based on it being between two dates + matching names in records)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables:

Salary Payslips:

| Payslip ID | Salary Deduction | Payslip Date | Employee Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | calc | 5/29/2022 | ABC |
| 2 | calc | 4/29/2022 | ABC |
| 3 | calc | 3/29/2022 | ABC |
| 4 | calc | 2/28/2022 | ABC |

Salary Deductions:

| Deduction ID | Deduction Date | Deduction Amount | Employee Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3/30/2022 | 50 | ABC |
| 2 | 5/10/2022 | 100 | ABC |
| 3 | 5/15/2022 | 100 | ABC |

I have two tables **"Salary Payslips" and "Salary Deductions.**" Deductions are removed from the total payslip amount (not shown here because its unnecessary to address the problem).

I am trying to calculate the total accrued deductions per salary cycle. (4/29/2022 -> 5/29/2022 is one salary cycle). In the example above, the total deductions between the two dates (i.e. the salary cycle) should be 200. I would want to have that number show up in the Salary Deduction field with Payslip ID=1 in the Salary Payslips table.

In the same fashion, the deduction on 3/30/2022 should show up in the salary payslips table at the record with payslip id =2.... and so on. The deduction amount in the payslip id = 3 should be zero since there were no deductions in during the period between 2/28-3/29.

*This should be done where the employee name is identical in both tables, so "ABC has 50 deducted from salary in cycle between 2/28/2022 and 3/29/2022" etc.*

**All of this should be updated recursively in a form. Hence, the control should be able to query the tables for the data and parse that onto the corresponding field in the form (and by association, the table).**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the [**`DSum`**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dsum-function-08f8450e-3bf6-45e2-936f-386056e61a32) domain aggregate which is available as an expression function, VBA function, and SQL function in MS Access (frontend GUI but not backend connection). Similarly, you can use `DLookUp` (which I advised on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72420008/1422451)) calling `SUM()` in expression argument.

Specifically, sum the `Salary Deduction` column in other table by corresponding `Employee Name` and where `Deduction Date` falls within date range of `PaySlip Date` and less than one month after using [`DateAdd`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dateadd-function-63befdf6-1ffa-4357-9424-61e8c57afc19).

**Expression** *(set to control source of `[Salary Deduction]` textbox in form design of `[Salary PaySlip]` form)*

```vb
=DSum("[Deduction Amount]", 
      "[Salary Deductions]", 
      "[Employee Name] = '" & [Employee Name] & "' AND
       [Deduction Date] >= #" & [PaySlip Date] & "#
                    AND <  #" & DateAdd("m", 1, [PaySlip Date]) & "#")
```

**VBA** *(programmatically calculate control source)*

```vb
Forms![Salary PaySlip]![Salary Deduction] = DSum( _
    "[Deduction Amount]", _
    "[Salary Deductions]", _
    "[Employee Name] = '" & Forms![Salary PaySlip]![Employee Name] & "' AND " _ 
     & "[Deduction Date] >= #" & Forms![Salary PaySlip]![PaySlip Date] & "#" _
     & "             AND <  #" & DateAdd("m", 1, Forms![Salary PaySlip]![PaySlip Date]) & "#" _
)
```

**SQL**

**`UPDATE`** *(using `DSum` to save data to table –cannot use [subquery](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-61.html))*

```sql
UPDATE [Salary PaySlip] p
SET p.[Salary Deduction] = DSum(
    "[Deduction Amount]", 
    "[Salary Deductions]", 
    "[Employee Name] = '" & p.[Employee Name] & "' AND
     [Deduction Date] >= #" & p.[PaySlip Date] & "#
                  AND <  #" & DateAdd("m", 1, p.[PaySlip Date]) & "#"
)
```

---

Alternatively, you can use a correlated aggregate subquery which can have performance  issues for large enough data. Hopefully, one day soon the MS Access team will [add support for window functions](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/2b2671a8-b67b-ec11-a81b-000d3a7c83cc) (per SQL ANSI 2003) to the Access SQL dialect!

**`SELECT`** *(using correlated aggregate subquery)*

```sql
SELECT p.[PaySlip ID],
       (SELECT SUM([Deduction Amount])
        FROM [Salary Deductions] d
        WHERE d.[Employee Name] = p.[Employee Name]
          AND d.[Deduction Date] >= p.[PaySlip Date]
                             AND <  DateAdd('m', 1, p.[PaySlip Date])
       ) AS [Salary Deduction],
       p.[PaySlip Date]
       p.[Employee Name]
FROM [Salary Payslips] p
```

Comment: When I try to put the VBA code in I'm getting a syntax / missing operator error

Comment: Also when I am running the control source code I get #Name? error

Comment: I made slight edits to both. Both assumes you have form controls named the same as your table names. Adjust as needed.

Comment: Now the control source code generates #ERROR. All the table references have been verified to match the database naming. Let me check the vba code now.

Comment: Still getting syntax / missing operator error on the VBA code

Comment: Also SQL queries not working sadly. just getting a table of empty records when i click datasheet view.

Comment: Issues are likely due to table/form control names and data types not aligning. Check even the form name, assumed to be same as table name (with spaces). What you posted may not be actual names. Also, this solution expects `Deduction Amount` is a number and `Deduction Date` is a date/time column.

Comment: Here's the vba code that worked. I don't know how it's different from yours but please update your answer so i can mark it with a check mark. thanks for the help

Comment: Forms![Salary Payslip]![Salary Deduction] = DSum("[Deduction Amount]", "[Salary Deductions]", "[Employee Name]='" & Forms![Salary Payslip]![Employee Name] & "' AND" & "[Deduction Date] <= #" & Forms![Salary Payslip]![Payslip Date] & "#" & " AND [Deduction Date] > #" & DateAdd("m", -1, [Forms]![Salary Payslip]![Payslip Date]) & "#")

Comment: Hmmm...I see a redundant concatenation `& "' AND" & "[Deduction Date]` and without space in front of `AND ` it should raise syntax issue. I do notice you reversed the date range. Perfectly ok to fine tune a proposed answer to meet final needs. Glad to help!

Comment: One issue that can cause a problem is if an employee name contains single or double quote (i.e., O'Reilly, Clark "Superman" Kent) which is why you should use `EmployeeID` as advised in last answer! Happy coding!